# reference foreign key sybase query

Tags: sybase

the function sp_helpconstraint will give me the reference foreign key of a table

example : sp_helpconstraint TAB1

FK_TAB1 TAB1 FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES TABREFERENCE(ID)

I am doing a query , inside of it I want to know the reference tables.

Answer (score 3):

[This example from Sybase.com](http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/sprocs126.htm) is quite illuminating:

For example, sp_helpconstraint output on the store_employees table in pubs3 looks similar to:

```
name                         defn
---------------------------  --------------------------------
store_empl_stor_i_272004000  store_employees FOREIGN KEY
                             (stor_id) REFERENCES stores(stor_id)
store_empl_mgr_id_288004057  store_employees FOREIGN KEY
                             (mgr_id) SELF REFERENCES
                             store_employees(emp_id)
store_empl_2560039432        UNIQUE INDEX( emp_id) :
                             NONCLUSTERED, FOREIGN REFERENCE 

(3 rows affected)

Total Number of Referential Constraints: 2
Details:
-- Number of references made by this table: 2
-- Number of references to this table: 1
-- Number of self references to this table: 1
```

In other words, `store_employees` has 2 foreign key constraints:

- `store` where the employee works
- `store_employee` indicating that person's manager

Note how a table's FK can point at itself.